# Check to see if an iframe has scrollbars visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone knows how to check to see if the content in an iframe is overflowing and the scrollbars are visible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if the element's `scrollHeight` is greater than the `clientHeight`, or if the element's `scrollWidth` is greater than the `clientWidth`. This can be done with those properties directly, or by using helper methods provided by jQuery.

[MDN: element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

> If the element's content generated a vertical scrollbar, the
> scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum clientHeight the element
> would require in order to fit all the content in the viewpoint without
> using a vertical scrollbar. When an element's content does not
> generate a vertical scrollbar, then its scrollHeight property is equal
> to its clientHeight property. This can mean either the content is too
> short to require a scrollbar or that the the element has CSS style
> overflow value of visible (non-scrollable).

Comment: Does this method require that the content of the iframe be hosted on the same server, or can it be cross-domain?

Comment: It can be either because the iframe element is in your domain. The content is not (necessarily), but the content is going to ultimately define the iframe's scrollWidth and scrollHeight and not matter otherwise.

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work, I get the same result for both, and they are both the height of the element.   function checkScroll() {
   var intElemScrollHeight = document.getElementById('websiteView').scrollHeight;
   var intElemClientHeight = document.getElementById('websiteView').clientHeight;

   alert(intElemScrollHeight);
   alert(intElemClientHeight);
  }

Comment: I did not real the iframe scrollWidth/Height were not relevant to the visible scroll bars. It must be defined within the iframe, maybe on a JS object that will not trigger a same origin error.

Answer (score 2):

in general you should compare the delta of the element's scrollHeight/scrollWidth and offsetHeight/offsetWidth. 
if positive then 'we got a winner'.
but.. when looking for scrollbars in an iframe, things get a little bit trickier:

```
var frm=document.getElementById("frm");
var iIsVrScrollBar =  frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight>frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.offsetHeight ? 1 : 0;
var iIsHrScrollBar = frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollWidth>frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.offsetWidth ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You should add that this works only if the iframe src comes from the same origin as the web page that hosts it. An example error would be: "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a frame with origin "https://.....".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the code to get it to work.

1) the IFRAME & contents are on the same website/folder structure

2) the procedure is instigated by setting "sizewindow" to TRUE

3) it snippet is part of a timer function set at anout 0.5 seconds

4) tested on IE11, FF34 & 35, Chrome 31 & 40, & Opera 12.6

5) active code sizes the window to just larger than content,

see http://www.users.waitrose.com/~cresby/map2.htm

```
if (sizewindow){
  if(iIsVrScrollBar==1) { 
   frm.style.height = (frm.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight+20); 
   iIsVrScrollBar =  (frm.scrollWidth!=frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollWidth) ? 1 : 0;
   if(iIsVrScrollBar==0) sizewindow=false;
 }else{
   frm.style.height = (frm.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight-10);
   iIsVrScrollBar =  (frm.scrollWidth!=frm.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollWidth) ? 1 : 0;
   if(iIsVrScrollBar==1) {frm.style.height = (frm.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight+10);}
 }
}
```